# Как создавать и работать с большими числами?

Tags: c#, математика, длинная-арифметика

Вопрос, как правильно создать кастомное число.

Задача следующая, мне нужно будет работать с числами превосходящие размер long. операции стандартные

- умножение
- деление
- сложение
- Вычитание
- отображение в двоичном виде.

Хотелось бы узнать есть ли стандартный функционал для работы с подобными числами ?

Если не стандартный а полностью кастомный, то на ум приходит следующее:

Как вариант первое что приходит на ум - это объект внутри которого будет массив бит где будет храниться число в двоичном виде, однако возможно есть стандартные или же обще принятые практики работы с подобными данными ?

И второй вопрос, это как сделать быстрое умножение / деление / сложение / вычитание ?

Понятно что для этого потребуется перегрузить операторы, но есть ли быстрые подходы к умножению чисел? Спрашиваю потому как, если я буду хранить число в виде массива байтов то умножение двоичного числа на двоичное в столбик может быть дольше чем перемножение двух стандартных чисел. Иначе говоря мне не хотелось бы иметь циклы и сложные логические конструкции...

Comment: э? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-6.0

Comment: `BigInteger` - велосипед уже изобретён.

Comment: `но есть ли быстрые подходы к умножению чисел?` [здесь поищите](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/System.Runtime.Numerics/src/System/Numerics).

Comment: Насколько большими должны быть числа? В `decimal` влезут? Какова должна быть точность? Может, `double` годится?

Comment: [Алгоритм Карацубы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Алгоритм_Карацубы) - быстрое умножение.

Comment: Вам придётся делать циклы и сложные логические конструкции. Карацуба - самый простой из не медленных алгоритмов - уже достаточно сложен. А действительно быстрый требует быстрого преобразования Фурье - очень сложная теория и очень сложная реализация. Зато интересно.